# I am getting an error message whenever I try and run this

Tags: python

```
score = input("what you score bro: ")
if score > 1000:
  print("winner")
else:
  print("loser")
```

(I am a complete noob). Idk why im getting an error looks right to me.

I tried it on my own then I watched the video again and looked at the bald guys code and mine looks the same idk whats wrong

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error message that you're getting. I *presume* that you're getting an error relating to your attempt to compare (`>`) a string (`score`) to an integer (`1000`). So, hint: convert the `score` you get from `input` from a string to an integer first, before attempting to compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a well-formulated question, but that doesn't mean newcomers shouldn't be helped out. Python relies on proper spacing.

If that's not your issue, you need to know that python will take input as a string, so you need to cast it explicitly to an integer

The following will work. Note the spacing and the explicit cast to an integer type:

```
score = input("what you score bro: ")
score = int(score)
if score > 1000:
    print("winner")
else:
    print("retard")
```

Comment: Thx bro it worked I really appreciate you taking the time out to answer me hope you have a good rest of your day G.